# React to select default value of a drop-down

Tags: reactjs

In my code, I want to make it a default selected value if there is only one.

As of now the code looks as follows:

```
<select 
  name="something"
  value={this.props.parentProps.value}
  <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

The idea here is to have the only option selected, if there is only one.
I could copy them out to and array within the code if needed:

```
<select options={something}
```

What would you recommend?

Basically I want something like:

```
if(only one option)
  Select(that one);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
<select 
  name="something"
  value={this.props.parentProps.value}
  <option value="" disabled selected={options.length === 1}>--Select--</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

this `options.length === 1` will return true or false that will trigger the selected